# How to access parent window window when the modal window is open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table, clicking on each rows pops up a modal window in a chaining fashion i.e if I click on the row of the modal window it will create another modal window.

However, I am not able to access the parent window while all the modal windows are open. I want the parent window and the two modal windows generated to be accessible at the same time.

My snippet is here :
https://jsfiddle.net/youser/xm4uzvLk/

The HTML code goes below:

```
<html>
<head>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.6/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.6/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js'></script>

<script src = https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>


<body>
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">On click row  popup will get open </h3>
    </div>
    <table id="jobs" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Job Title</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Date Posted</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!--Made it easier, so no more redundant copypasta in other pages-->
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>VP Marketing</td>
                <td>Devify</td>
                <td>22.38</td>
                <td>222 Lillian Hill</td>
                <td>2015-02-17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Administrative</td>
                <td>Skiba</td>
                <td>10.92</td>
                <td>3 Corscot Terrace</td>
                <td>2015-02-03</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Database Admini</td>
                <td>Dynazzy</td>
                <td>36.72</td>
                <td>5082 Butterfield Ter</td>
                <td>2015-01-30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Quality Control</td>
                <td>Realmix</td>
                <td>23.48</td>
                <td>598 Independence Cir</td>
                <td>2015-02-19</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Health Coach II</td>
                <td>Linkbuzz</td>
                <td>17.11</td>
                <td>18 Donald Plaza</td>
                <td>2015-02-17</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Biostatistician</td>
                <td>Roomm</td>
                <td>36.37</td>
                <td>3 Almo Terrace</td>
                <td>2015-02-16</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>


          <tr>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$3,600</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$5,000</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Financial Controller</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$4,200</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$5,300</td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!---- second modal window with datatable -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table id="example2" class="table table-striped table-hover responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>

          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Mark Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Bristol</td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Steve Murchison</td>
            <td>Director</td>
            <td>Los Angeles</td>

          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
   <style type="text/css" class="init"> body {
       font-size: 140%;
   }
   </style>


</body>
</html>
```

Below is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var companyTable=  $('#jobs').DataTable();   
    $('#jobs').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
        });
     $('#example').on('click', 'tr', function () {

        var table = $('#example2').DataTable();
        $('#myModal2').modal("show");
        });


});
```

Please help me achieve this requirement.
Thanks.

Comment: The idea of the _modal_ window is, that you can't access the main window while the  modal is open. Use modeless window instead.

Comment: @Teemu is there any option that I need to mention ? how to make them modeless? Any reference would be helpful. Thanks